# Angular (or JavaScript) , create a button that updates a field and refreshes list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
'use strict';

app.controller("derpCont", function  ($scope,  derptod) {

        $scope.derp = derptod.query();
        $scope.deptod = function() {

            derptod.update()


        };
      });
```

When I click the button I can see the thing trying to update something, but I get a 404 error message, if I pass variables inside the method I get 500 errors. How do I write a method inside the UserTodos.update(). so I will update ONLY {{todo.completed}} from true to false and viceversa using ngresoruce

this is my service

```
 app.factory('derptod', function($resource) {
        var cray = $resource('jpholder/tod', {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    return cray;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your service would need to return an object with the "Update" property you are trying to call like so...

```
app.factory('UserTodos', function($resource) {
    var update = function (todos, index, value) {
        // Do Something
        todos[index].completed = value;
    }
    return {
        Update:update
    };
});
```

Secondly, if you want to modify the todo you can do so in the controller or in the service. Either way I would pass the index of the todo to the controller method along with the value like this.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="UpdateTodo($index, true)" 
                  class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
```

Finally in the controller you can do the manipulation or pass everything to the service.

```
$scope.UpdateTodo = function(index, value) {
    // Use the service
    UserTodos.Update($scope.todos, index, value);

    // Or what I would do in a hurry
    $scope.todos[index].completed = value;

};
```

Comment: As soon as I replace this I get this error: angular.js:12221 TypeError: UserTodos.query is not a function....is it because I'm using ngresource ?

Comment: wow...Thanks man. The first option didnt work but the second one did. I''ll elaborate. If you can could you explain me a little bit what you did. like why index? and this line $scope.todos[index].completed = value;...ohh I had to get rid of the Update:update  and replace it with only 1 update tho

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the service call. It should have been capitalized like this UserTodos.Update($scope.todos, index, value); then the original return statement would work in the service. I updated the service method to reflect the implementation as well.

Comment: @brohymn,  The reason for $index is that the "todos" is a list or an array and you want to modify a specific item/object in the list also referred to as an index. So angular has a helper you can use to identify the specific item in the array "$index". The value of $index is an integer between 0-N determined by the amount of items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can just update your todos model if I understand your problem correctly.

```
$scope.UpdateTodo = function(index) {
  UserTodos.update();
  $scope.todo[index].completed = $scope.todo[index].completed === 'COMPLETED' ? 'INCOMPLETE' : 'COMPLETED';
};
```

In your HTML:

```
<td> <button type="button" ng-click="UpdateTodo($index)" class="btn btn-info">Update</button> </td>
```

Comment: I get this error :
angular.js:12221 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.UpdateTodo (SkillController.js:13)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13036), <anonymous>:4:325)

and when I click in the next element is the same but different ID...is it soemthing on my service ?

angular.js:12221 TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.UpdateTodo (SkillController.js:13)